# Erro uninitialized constant Devise::OmniAuthCallbacksController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth, office365

While implementing OmniAuth in devise under rails 4 i get the following error:

```
uninitialized constant Devise::OmniAuthCallbacksController
app/controllers/usuarios/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Its like i am unable to extend Devise::OmniAuthCallbacksController

my file is:

```
class Usuarios::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniAuthCallbacksController
   def all
  end
  alias_method :office365, :all 
end
```

My gems

gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-office365'

User model

```
class Usuario < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, 
  :omniauth_providers => [:outlook365]

end
```

Thanks.

Comment: please post you user model

Comment: @AmitSharma updated post with user model

Comment: do you have this in your routes file `devise_for :Usuarios, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "usuarios/omniauth_callbacks" }`